# Comprimir multi-volumen usando python

Tags: python, archivo, zip, filewriter, winrar

Cómo puedo comprimir con python un archivo en varios volumenes .zip o .rar. Estoy intentando con zipfile, pero solo me deja crear un .zip resultante. Mi idea es intentar simular algo parecido a la idea de winrar de tomar un archivo origen y especificar un tamaño s y crear n bloques de tamaño s.
Por ejemplo, tengo el archivo base file de tamaño 10mg, si defino s=2 como el tamaño, entonces quiero obtener 10/2=5 archivos de tamaño 2mg, por ejemplo: resultado: file0.zip, file1.zip, file2.zip, file3.zip, file4.zip.

Alguna idea. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: podrías dividir en bloques de lectura el archivo original, y de acuerdo a los resultantes crear los archivos zip con un bucle  en el rango obtenido por la división agregandole al nombre cada iteración. como cuando se usa sockets para el envío de archivos.Si pones algo de código de lo que estás intentando será más facil ayudarte.

Comment: Para ayudarte debes publicar el código que tengas escrito, de manera que sólo falte completar la operación multi-archivo.

Comment: hola, siento lo del codigo, es q no tengo nada aun, solo la idea, de usar esto de compirmir como un complemento para otra cosa, pero muchas gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este código genera *n* archivos .zip a partir de un archivo "grande". Es un código mínimo que no genera multi-volumenes, sólo una serie de .zip separados que hay que unir a mano. Se puede mejorar, obviamente:

La función `write_block` recibe un block de bytes, el nombre del archivo de donde provienen, y un número de secuencia para el .zip a generar. La función crea el .zip, graba el block y termina.

La función `write_zip_file` recibe un nombre de archivo a leer y el número de bytes a poner en cada .zip.

El archivo entonces es leido de a bloques, generando un .zip aparte por cada uno.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

block_size = 100_000

def write_block(block, filename, parte):
    zip_name = f"{filename}-parte-{parte}"
    zip_arch = ZipFile(f"{zip_name}.zip", "w")
    zip_info = ZipInfo(zip_name)
    zip_arch.writestr(zip_info, block)
    zip_arch.close()


def write_zip_file(filename, block_size):
    with open(filename, "rb") as entrada:
        parte = 1
        while block := entrada.read(block_size):
            write_block(block, filename, parte)
            parte += 1


write_zip_file("Tweets.txt", block_size)
```

Comment: Me sirvio mucho el codigo anterior, solo una dudita, que puede que sea una boberia de mi parte preguntar :D; lo de "unir a mano" tengo alguna manera de hacerlo desde codigo, es q suponiendo que los descomprima en un ciclo uno a uno me quedan todos separados, luego unirlos para mi seria moverme por cada uno de estos resultantes y leerlos bit a bit y unirlo con los otros, pero creo que no es muy buena idea la mia. Alguna sugerencia porfa

Comment: @Eduar2 tu idea no está nada mal, intenta hacerlo, lo más probable es que te funcione

Comment: @Christian, voy a eso, a ver si sirve :D. Thanks